# Disabling spring security for google login in application

Tags: spring, spring-boot, authentication, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I have a spring boot application with default level spring security and i am using **auth.userDetailsService(customuserservice)** for the user authentication part. Apart from that we are using Google login button. My configuration file is

```
`http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/","/securitylogin").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/SecondMainPage")
            .hasAnyRole("SUPERADMIN","ADMIN","USER")
            .anyRequest()
            .authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/securitylogin") //login
            .usernameParameter("username") //optional
            .passwordParameter("password") //optional
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/loggedin")
            .permitAll()
            .and()
            .logout()
            .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/")
            .invalidateHttpSession(true)
            .permitAll();`
```

Authentication part is working as expected but not the Google login part. After the Google login i am getting the email and fetching his details from the server and redirecting to one controller but the controller his reloading n number of times. I dont know why the single method is getting reloaded again and again.

> http.antMatcher("/loginwithgoogle/**").anonymous();

If i use the above line the Google login part is working fantastically but the normal login authentication is not getting access.

> web.ignoring().antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/loginwithgoogle");

I tried the above one too but the same controller is reloading again and again for n number of times. Please help me to move on further. Anything else am i missing or am i going in the wrong way??

Answer (score 0):

Actually i tried the same thing before but no idea why i didnt getting succeeded but the following thing works for me and updated the same if it helps for anyone.

```
http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/loginwithgoogle/**").anonymous() //works this order
            .anyRequest().authenticated() // with this line too
            .antMatchers("/","/securitylogin").permitAll()
```

i dont know whether there is seperate order will be there or not but i tried the anonymous() seperately but didnt worked. The above is working perfectly.

**UPDATE 11.09.2018** 
The Google login is working perfectly but roles are not working (ie) User can able to access the admin pages and exception handling is not working correctly.